# Populate a drop down box with values from database using php and sql

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu

I want to have a drop down box that has a list of different sizes of item. I have a table called items in my database with an attribute inside it called sizes. This maps to a table called sizes which lists the different sizes with different prices etc.

I simply want to create a drop down box within the items web page which lists the sizes associated with that item. How can I use php to fetch the sizes and display them in a drop down box?

I have got items table which has a composite key of `item_id` and `size_id` which is mapped to sizes table which has a primary key of `size_id`.

I have tried to find information from the net but to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: [Here][1] is answer on your question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033570/display-data-from-sql-database-in-a-drop-down-menu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use HTML's `SELECT` and its `OPTION` something like:

```
<select name="mySelect"> 
    <?php $result= mysql_query('SELECT * FROM items'); ?> 
    <?php while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?> 
        <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['your_column_name']);?>"> 
            <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['your_column_name']); ?> 
        </option> 
    <?php } ?> 
</select>
```

Of course, you can add a `ORDER BY ...` to the sql query above for sorting. Then depending on your form method, you can access this by using `$_POST["mySelect"]` or `$_GET["mySelect"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can write two queries or you can use join to fetch values from both the tables at a time..
But for that I would like to know what type of mapping are you using between items table and sizes table..

Comment: I have got items table which has a composite key of item_id and size_id which is mapped to sizes table which has a primary key of size_id